# CSS Position Problems

Tags: html, css

Evening,

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="search" value="Search"><input type="button" class="searchimg" value="Search" />
```

CSS:

```
input.search {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #383838;
    margin: 7px 0 0 7px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #969696!important;
    background: #FEFEFE!important;
    height: 16px;
    width: 250px;
} 

input.searchimg { 
   text-indent: -99999px;
   width: 24px; 
   height: 24px; 
   display: inline;
   background: url(../images/search.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
   border: 0px;
   margin: 7px 0 0 0;
}
```

(search.jpg dimentions: 24x24px, 1px border is part of image, not CSS! http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/6779/searchr.png)

Top version shows how it's supposed to render, the bottom picture is showing how it is actually rendering, in all broswers. It is 2px higher than it's supposed to be. I'm not really sure why it's doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Does nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: Tested in Chromium 15 and it works as expected.  Replaced the search image with another 24px x 24px image. See http://jsfiddle.net/C4ayu/

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is also needed for it to render in Chrome and safari, it renders in Firefox without it using the method I mentioned below.

Comment: Also for this to work the margin properties need to be omitted.

Correction: They need to be declared seperately on each class, as margin-top: 7px; NOT margin: 7px 0 0 0;

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line `margin: 7px 0 0 7px;`

Answer (score 0):

Try `vertical-align:top` on `input.search { ... }` this should work because your input is affected by (previous?) inline styles.

For the future: it's easier to operate on elements styled with `display:inline-block` and it's well supported in browsers (IE 7 needs an small hack, IE 6 should be dead already).

Comment: It won't allow to me to answer my own question but I have now corrected this issue..

Have now fixed this issue. For reference: was corrected by editing the padding in the input.search class to

 padding-top: 5px;

Thanks.